# Alfresco activiti - move a document

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

i want to move my file on other directory when the workflow is approved, am working with activiti and i insert the following code

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoJavaScript">
      <activiti:field name="script">
        <activiti:expression>if(task.getVariableLocal('scwf_approveRejectOutcome') == 'Approve') {

    var dest = bpm_context.childByNamePath("nv");
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++)
    {
        bpm_package.children[i].move(dest);
    }</activiti:expression>
      </activiti:field>
</activiti:taskListener>
```

i get this error on alfresco:

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Exception while invoking TaskListener: Incompatible type set on field declaration 'script' for class org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoJavaScript. Declared value has type org.activiti.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression, while expecting org.dom4j.Element
```

how can i move my document with activiti?!!

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
  <activiti:field name="script">
    <activiti:string>
      if(task.getVariableLocal('scwf_approveRejectOutcome') == 'Approve') {

      var dest = bpm_context.childByNamePath("nv");
      for (var i = 0; i &lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++)
      {
        bpm_package.children[i].move(dest);
      }
    </activiti:string>
  </activiti:field>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tag to wrap the script content. As the error message suggests, it fails to assign a value of type `org.activiti.engine.impl.el.JuelExpression` to the `script` field of the task listener.

Using `activity:string` instead of `activity:expression` should work as expected:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoJavaScript">
      <activiti:field name="script">
        <activiti:string>
          if(task.getVariableLocal('scwf_approveRejectOutcome') == 'Approve') {

          var dest = bpm_context.childByNamePath("nv");
          for (var i = 0; i &lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++)
          {
            bpm_package.children[i].move(dest);
          }
        </activiti:string>
      </activiti:field>
</activiti:taskListener>
```

Comment: i did it and now i get this error :

org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Exception while invoking TaskListener: Incompatible type set on field declaration 'script' for class org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoJavaScript. Declared value has type org.activiti.engine.impl.el.FixedValue, while expecting org.dom4j.Element

Answer (score 0):

Try this, wrap code inside `<activiti:string>` to `<![CDATA[ your code ]]>`

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.jbpm.AlfrescoJavaScript">
      <activiti:field name="script">
        <activiti:string><![CDATA[
          if(task.getVariableLocal('scwf_approveRejectOutcome') == Approve') {
          var dest = bpm_context.childByNamePath("nv");
          for (var i = 0; i &lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++)
          {
            bpm_package.children[i].move(dest);
          }
       ]]> </activiti:string>
      </activiti:field>
</activiti:taskListener>
```

Or this:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
   <activiti:field name="script">
      <activiti:string><![CDATA[
          if(task.getVariableLocal('scwf_approveRejectOutcome') == 'Approve') {
              var dest = bpm_context.childByNamePath("nv");
              for (var i = 0; i &lt; bpm_package.children.length; i++)
              {
                bpm_package.children[i].move(dest);
              }
    ]]></activiti:string>
  </activiti:field>
</activiti:taskListener>
```